# Javascript set value of an input field

Tags: javascript, html, input, setattribute

Since while I cannot set the value of an input field with type=text.
Before, I always used something like this:

```
<input style="display: none" type="text" name="geo_poi" value="" id="geofeld" />
```

Then, in JavaScript i added code containing a line like this:

```
document.getElementById("geofeld").value = geo_poi;
```

This always worked. Maybe the new browsers don't want to support the method above anymore.

Comment: How come `.value = "whatever"` doesn't work for form elements? `oO`

Comment: what browser are you using ?

Comment: Chrome or Firefox, I also tested it in FireBug and in the console of chrome. But setAttribute("value", "anything") works as I supposed.

Answer (score 23):

So using the following method for setting attributes worked fine.

```
document.getElementById("geofeld").setAttribute("value", geo_poi);
```

Answer (score 2):

For situations when setAttribute does not yield any result *(think HTML5 user/password input)*, consider this:

```
document.getElementById("geofeld").setRangeText("text");
```

Answer (score -2):

HTML

---

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Item 1" id="item1" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Item 2" id="item2" />
```

JAVASCRIPT

---

```
$('#item1').blur(function() {
    var item1var = $('#item1').val();
    $('#item2').val(item1var);
});
```

Jsfiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6VG6w/)

Comment: This does not look like "Javascript" to me. You might be using some library.

Comment: @engineerX Probably jQuery

Comment: so this is javascript right?
<input type="text" onchange="passvalue()" placeholder="Item 1" id="item1" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Item 2" id="item2" />

<script>
function passvalue() {
var pValue = document.getElementById('item1').value;
document.getElementById('item2').value = pValue;

}
</script>